# how do I split from one variable into multiple variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry I'm new in Javascript and i need help. My problem is like this. I have one variable like this, ie:

```
abcdefg1234567hijklmnop
```

that variable consists of 3 parts: string,number,string. The problem is I don't know how to split them become:

```
var1=abcdefg
var2=1234567
var3=hijklmnop
```

so I can send them to another php file with ajax post. Is there a way to make it happens? thanks.

Comment: Please show your efforts when asking question. Just saying _I'm newbie, please help_ is not enough. And this is very easy with regex.

Comment: you could use a regex

Comment: I have already find, but doesn't suitable for my case.

Comment: `I have already find, but doesn't suitable for my case` - or you used the wrong one

Comment: regex? ok I'll learn it first.

Comment: **Hint:** Check these keywords, Character class with range, `\d`, `+` and `*` and Capturing groups.

Comment: please Tushar don't mad of me, i really don't know javascript much.

Comment: Try [`([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rI7nS2/1). Check explanation in the right top corner. To get started with regex check [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi I'm not mad at your, please try first and then ask question next time. :)

Comment: I still say `[a-z]` is an assumption on your part @Tushar

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, looking at the input string in OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regEXP

```
var str = "abcdefg1234567hijklmnop",            
    result = /^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)$/.exec(str);

console.log(result[0]); // abcdefg1234567hijklmnop
console.log(result[1]); // abcdefg
console.log(result[2]); // 1234567
console.log(result[3]); // hijklmnop
```

https://regex101.com/ - nice place to create, understand and test regExp

HIW:

1. `/^$/` - `/` - Delimiters of regex literal. `^` - beggining of the string, `$` - end
2. `([a-zA-Z]+)` - capturing group 1; `+` pass to any of `[a-zA-Z]` chars one or more times. `[a-zA-Z]`: Matches characters from `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`, so matching all the alphabets.
3. `(\d+)` - capturing group 2; `\d` - matches single digit, `+` matches one or more of the previous characters. `\d = [0-9]`
4. `([a-zA-Z]+)` - capturing group 3; same as 2.

You can read more about regExp here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

To learn regex use http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi no problem ^

Comment: I don't know @Tushar, it seems still complicated too me, I tried and just worked for me, please don't be mad, i really don't know javascript much. If I know and get a suitable from google, I don't asking, truely. I just need help.

Comment: I don't know what regex is @Tushar, I just knew right now.

Comment: wow, your explanation is great @Andrew, I'm learning from you right now.

Comment: wow, that thing was called by **regex** is more clearly in my eyes now. Thanks a lot @Andrew.

Comment: wow, Thank you @Tushar for editing, more clearly now, you are very kind people.

Comment: @Tushar and Andrew please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner

```
/(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)/.exec('abcdefg1234567hijklmnop').slice(1).forEach(function(v, n) { window['var'+(n+1)] = v; });
```

or

```
/(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)/.exec('abcdefg1234567hijklmnop').slice(1).forEach(function(v, n) {
    this['var'+(n+1)] = v;
}.bind(window));
```

replace `window` with another object to create var*n* on if you want

Comment: You can also use `[a-z]+` instead of `\D+` as it is more specific and use `i` flag _if needed_.

Comment: `string,number,string` ... [a-z]+ would be an assumption on my part

Comment: this will create `var1` `var2` `var3` just like you asked for in your question :p

Comment: i give **alert(res)** to your second code @JaromandaX , but the result is **undefined**

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi Use `alert(var1);`, `alert(var2);` and `alert(var3);`. Oh, don't use `alert` use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: res ins't required - forgot to get rid of it like in the one liner

Comment: I used console.log as your suggestion, then it works @Jaromanda, thanks for your help. +1 for you.

Comment: @Jaromanda please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)